# Reordering binary search tree after removing an item

Tags: c, binary-search-tree

I'm working on a binary search tree in C. I believe my removeBST function is deleting properly, but I don't think the tree is being reordered correctly.

**This is my remove function:**

```
int removeBST(struct TreeNode** rootRef, int data)
{  
  struct TreeNode* heir;
  struct TreeNode* prev;

  if(*rootRef == NULL)
  {
    return 0;
  }

  if(data < (*rootRef)->data)
  {
    return removeBST(&(*rootRef)->left, data);
  }
  else if(data > (*rootRef)->data)
  {
    return removeBST(&(*rootRef)->right, data);
  }
  else
  {
    struct TreeNode* temp;

    if((*rootRef)->right == NULL)
    {
      temp = *rootRef;
      *rootRef = (*rootRef)->left;
      free(temp);
      return 1;
    }
    else if((*rootRef)->left == NULL)
    {
      temp = *rootRef;
      *rootRef = (*rootRef)->right; 
      free(temp);
      return 1;
    }
    else
    {
      heir = (*rootRef)->left;
      prev = *rootRef;

      while(heir->right != NULL)
      {
         prev = heir;
         heir = heir->right;
      } 

      (*rootRef)->data = heir->data;

      if(prev != *rootRef)
      {
        prev->right = heir->left;
      }
      else
      {
        prev->left = heir->left;
      }
      free(heir);
      return 1;
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

**This is where the function is called:**

```
for(i = -4; i < 25; i+=4)
 {
   n = removeBST(&bst, i);
   if(!n) printf("remove did not find %d\n", i);  
 }
```

**This is my expected output:**

> test tree: 1 2 3 1 4 1 2 5 1 2 3 1 
>  tree leaves: 1 1 1 1 1 
>  tree depth
>   = 5 
> tree balanced = 1
>  tree isBST = 0 
> another test tree: 1 2 3 4 1 5 1 2 6 1 2 3  
> tree leaves: 1 1 1 1  
> tree depth = 6 
> tree balanced = 0 
> tree
>   isBST = 0 
> notBST: 1 3 8 5 6 7 10  
> notBST leaves: 1 8 6 10  
> notBST
>   depth = 3 
> notBST balanced = 1 
> notBST isBST = 0 
> empty tree:  
> filled
>   BST: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22  
> BST
>   leaves: 0 6 12 17  
> BST depth = 8 
> BST minimum value = 0 
> BST balanced =
>   0 
> BST isBST = 1 
> remove did not find -4 
> remove did not find 24 
> BST
>   after removes: 1 2 3 5 6 7 9 10 11 13 14 15 17 18 19 21 22  
> BST
>   leaves: 1 6 13 18 (PROBLEM HERE) 
> BST depth = 6 (PROBLEM HERE) 
> BST minimum value = 1 
> BST balanced =
>   0 
> BST isBST = 1

**This is my actual output:**

> test tree: 1 2 3 1 4 1 2 5 1 2 3 1 
> tree leaves: 1 1 1 1 1 
> tree depth =
>   5 
> tree balanced = 1 
> tree isBST = 0 
> another test tree: 1 2 3 4 1 5 1 2
>   6 1 2 3 
> tree leaves: 1 1 1 1 
> tree depth = 6 
> tree balanced = 0 
> tree
>   isBST = 0 
> notBST: 1 3 8 5 6 7 10 
> notBST leaves: 1 8 6 10 
> notBST depth
>   = 3 
> notBST balanced = 1 
> notBST isBST = 0 
> empty tree: 
> filled BST: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 
> BST leaves: 0 6
>   12 17 
> BST depth = 8 
> BST minimum value = 0 
> BST balanced = 0 
> BST isBST =
>   1 
> remove did not find -4 
> remove did not find 24 
> BST after removes: 1 2
>   3 5 6 7 9 10 11 13 14 15 17 18 19 21 22 
> BST leaves: 1 6 13 17 (PROBLEM HERE)
> BST
>   depth = 7 (PROBLEM HERE)
> BST minimum value = 1 
> BST balanced = 0 
> BST isBST = 1

As you can see, my BST leaves after removal are not correct, and the depth is wrong, so I assume it's not reordering properly.

I don't think this is the problem, but just in case, here's my printLeaves function (as a side note, if I wanted to print a newline after the last leaf is printed, how would I do that):

```
void printLeaves(struct TreeNode* root)
{
  if(root->left == NULL && root->right == NULL)
  {
    printf("%d ", root->data);
  }
  else
  {
    if(root->left != NULL)
    {
      printLeaves(root->left);
    }
    if(root->right != NULL)
    {
      printLeaves(root->right);
    }
  }
}
```

And my maxDepth function:

```
int maxDepth(struct TreeNode* root)
{ 
  struct TreeNode* current = root;

  if(current == NULL)
  {
    return 0;
  }
  else
  {
    int leftDepth = maxDepth(current->left);
    int rightDepth = maxDepth(current->right);

    if(leftDepth > rightDepth)
    {
      return (leftDepth+1);
    }
    else
    {
      return (rightDepth+1);
    }
  }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: If you don't start accepting people's answers, sooner or later they're just going to stop answering. For example, you wouldn't be where you are now with *this* code without the answers from [**this question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36592293/having-trouble-with-a-binary-search-tree-remove-function).

Comment: Accept answers in what way? Sorry, I'm fairly new to stackoverflow and don't know the protocols. I implemented your suggestion and upvoted it, as it was correct. I made a new post for this as I assume the problem is unrelated to my other post, which you already answered.

Comment: Ah, just realized what the check mark is for..,.. Sorry about that.